# How does the Bezos API mandate affect Database Design?

Tags: api, microservices, api-design

The [Bezos API Mandate](https://nordicapis.com/the-bezos-api-mandate-amazons-manifesto-for-externalization/) speaks in volumes about how externalized APIs must be designed.

However it is unclear from the points listed in the mandate as how databases for microservices are maintained.

1. Do teams (services) use a shared schema and manage data handling/processing with a separate microservice on their own (DAO service)?
2. Do teams (services) have their own isolated schemas and database engines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the 12-factors of microservices.

The question to your answer in simple words is, Every microservices is having its isolated database( maybe the dedicated table or in NOSQL it's separate bucket for that microservice). And most important, only that microservice can interact with its databases: all other services must go through that service (e.g. via REST/HTTP or a message bus).

Read this link which gives a detailed explanation.

https://12factor.net/backing-services

See below URL::

https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-reference-architecture-nginx-twelve-factor-app/